# Returning a vector of unique_ptr by reference

Tags: c++

Here is my code

```
class Carl{
    public:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> asd;
    Carl(){
        asd.push_back(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(4)));
        asd.push_back(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(2)));
    }

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> & getVec(){
        return asd;
    }
};



int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Carl v; 
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> * oi = &(v.getVec());

    //how to print first element?
    return 0;
}
```

My goal is to access the unique pointer w/o giving up the ownership.

My question is that, if I return by reference and catch the reference's address by using a vector pointer, will it work?

I know that receiving by reference will work better, but i am trying to find out if it's possible to receive by pointer.

Comment: If you share the unique pointers with unknown code you are just asking for dangling references/pointers. You then have to be careful when you invalidate them and in effect gave up unique ownership. Maybe using shared pointers would be cleaner depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> * oi
```

1) dereference the pointer:

```
*oi;
```

2) access first element of vector:

```
(*oi)[0];
```

3) access int that the `unique_ptr` points to:

```
*((*oi)[0]);
```

The above should work, but I do not think it is a good solution. There is almost always something wrong with the design when such a solution seems necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this code is perfectly valid:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> * oi = &(v.getVec());
```

It's also unnecessarily confusing. Now if you want to access the first element, you'd have to type `(*oi)[0]`. Whereas if you used a reference, you could just type `oi[0]`.

The extra typing becomes more odious when you want the first `int`, `*(*oi)[0]` vs `*oi[0]`.

Comment: oooo i see. i was trying to access it by `std::cout<<*(oi[0])<<std::endl;`. ty for the correction. Can you explain to me why that doesn't work?